# Remove all elements after a position in an array of objects in Javascript using splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am wondering if there is an easy way to splice out all elements after a key position.

```
array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX)
```

The docs say the 2nd element that specifies the number of elements to be removed is a required field, is there a caveat to get this done?

P.S - Not looking for the normal brute force solutions.

Comment: It's very easy try yourself in console: `var a = [1,2,3,4,5]; a.splice(2); console.log(a);`.

Comment: What the heck are you asking here? [**Array.splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is an incredibly simple method that takes a starting index and an optional "how many" argument, what is it you don't understand, and what would this "brute force" solution that you're not looking for look like ?

Comment: *"Remove all elements after a position in a JSON array in Javascript using splice"* By the time you're using `slice`, it's not JSON anymore. JSON is a **textual** notation for data interchange.

Comment: @adeneo really nonconstructive comment, you should read the question carefully or not comment at all, thanks anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, agree

Comment: @Rohan: adeneo's comment was a comment, not an answer, and I see no indication that he didn't read the question. The question is quite vague, there's no reason adeneo shouldn't ask you to clarify.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i wasn't seeking an explanation to how splice worked in javascript, but if there was a way to use splice for the problem i had, so both my statements hold.

Comment: @dfsq: According to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12), the second argument is required.

Comment: The operative phrase here is that you are looking to `truncate` an array after a certain position.  T.J. shows how to just set `.length` to do that.  Also, what you have is a javascript array.  JSON is a text format.

Comment: I was asking what you were really asking, as it's not easy to understand. You have "JSON arrays", but there's no such thing, and you want to use `splice`, but at the same time not use `splice`, and you don't want a "brute force solution", what ever that is, and T.J.'s solution surely is as "brute force" as they come, but it's still probably exactly what you're looking for ?

Comment: @adeneo: *"You have "JSON arrays", but there's no such thing"* Sure there is: `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"` That's a JSON array. ;-D *(I know you know that, just trying a bit of levity.)*

Comment: @adeneo forget it, TJ's solution isn't brute force, never said i didn't want to use splice. And i used json arrays in haste, apologies on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is an easy way to splice out all elements after a key position in a json array.

If it's *all* elements after a key position, you do this:

```
array.length = theKeyPosition;
```

E.g.:

```
var array = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six"
];
var theKeyPosition = 3;
array.length = theKeyPosition; // Remove all elements starting with "four"
```

If you don't yet know the key position, in an ES5 environment (and this can be shimmed), you use `filter`:

```
var array = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six"
];
var keep = true;
array = array.filter(function(entry) {
    if (entry === "four") {
        keep = false;
    }
    return keep;
});
```

That's using strings, but you can easily change `if (entry === "four") {` to `if (entry.someProperty === someValue) {` for your array of objects.

Comment: Thanks, didn't assume it would be so simple !

Comment: @Rohan: No worries. :-) If this answered your question, please remember to accept the answer (but only if it did).

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is actually optional for `Array.prototype.splice()` and the desired behaviour can be achieved using only the first argument.

For example (copied form the accepted answer):

```js
const array = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six"
];
const theKeyPosition = 3;
array.splice(theKeyPosition+1); // Remove all elements starting with "four"
console.log(array);
```

However, I still prefer setting the length property as it's supposed to be faster (I can't find the JSPerf result, please help me here).

Read more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) or on [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62316911/1079901) to a similar question.