# Javascript array length modification implications

Tags: javascript, arrays

I noticed something while trying to extend `Array.prototype`. I essentially wanted to write a method which allows for the deletion of the last item in an array:

```
Array.prototype.removeLast = function() {
    delete this[this.length - 1];
};
```

This doesn't produce the result I expected:

```
>>> var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
>>> arr.removeLast();
undefined
>>> arr
[ 1, 2, undefined ]
```

So I tried another method:

```
Array.prototype.removeLast = function() {
    this.length--;
};
```

And I got the expected results.

```
>>> var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
>>> arr.removeLast();
undefined
>>> arr
[ 1, 2 ]
```

## Questions

1) Why isn't array-index deletion operating like object-key deletion? (With arrays the reference still seems to exist, but just references `undefined`. With objects, the reference seems to be deleted entirely.)

2) Is the `this.length--` method safe? Could it cause a memory leak, or does 
altering an object's `length` attribute also cause a check to run and delete any forgotten indices in the array?

3) Do the answers to either of the previous 2 questions vary based on the implementation?

4) What's a good implementation of `removeLast`?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all you shouldn't mutate the Array prototype. Secondly, `delete` removes an object on given index, but doesn't change the length of the array. Thirdly, there are native, better functions for it, like `pop()` or `splice()`, which will change the structure of the array.

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640216/memory-management-of-javascript-array

Comment: 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547315/is-it-an-antipattern-to-set-an-array-length-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: 3) and 4) are answered in 1) and 2)

Comment: While a good reference (from 2012), it's important to note that (1) quotes an old ECMA Standard and furthermore while a standard helps define expectations, it generally does not define how something is implemented (browsers behave differently when the standard is not specific), or when including a feature before it has made it into standard.

Comment: Also (2) suggests behavior I have seen not to work.  `length` at one time was protected in a certain browser.  Perhaps enough time as passed to not consider that browser necessary to support, but I disagree with the answer provided, based on my own experience.

Comment: I should also add that `arr.length=0` is a somewhat common way of manipulating the array (clearing it out), without losing its properties.  Again, this conflicts with the point I made above, where a certain legacy browser made *length* immutable.  I would gather that it's an edge-case that only needs to be noted and not a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MDN explains for the [deleting array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements):

> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.
>
> When the delete operator removes an array element, that element is no longer in the array. In the following example, trees[3] is removed with delete.

For your Array, you are trying to *delete* an index (with it, its value), which is performed using the the `delete` operator, but not in the way you think.  The index/value is removed, but how the JavaScript engine assembles the array and manipulates its properties (e.g., `length`) will not do what you think.  It will still display the missing index w/ `undefined`, which is what you see.

### Demonstration

To better demonstrate, if do `Object.keys( your_array )` you will see that the index that you deleted of your array does not exist; likewise, if you perform `Object.values( your_array )` you will see that the `undefined` is not returned.  For all intents and purposes you deleted the property (the index) and its associated value.

### Other considerations

You may consider using use `splice`, or `pop` (if last index), to remove the last element of the array; however, this isn't without recognizing their own effects:

- `splice` will reorder the array, shifting the values into new indexes; this is different from `delete`, which keeps everything at its original index
- `pop` will remove only the last item/index from the array
- `splice` and `pop` will both update the `length` property of the array

#### Example of `delete` vs `splice` vs `pop`

```js
console.log('\nDELETE');
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
delete trees[3];
console.log('array: ', trees);
console.log('keys: ', Object.keys(trees) );
console.log('values: ', Object.values(trees) );
console.log('length: ', trees.length );
trees.forEach(val=>console.log(val)); // notice no undefined


console.log('\nPOP');
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
trees.pop();
console.log('array: ', trees);
console.log('keys: ', Object.keys(trees) );
console.log('values: ', Object.values(trees) );
console.log('length: ', trees.length );
trees.forEach(val=>console.log(val));


console.log('\nSPLICE');
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
trees.splice(3,1);
console.log('array: ', trees);
console.log('keys: ', Object.keys(trees) );
console.log('values: ', Object.values(trees) );
console.log('length: ', trees.length );
trees.forEach(val=>console.log(val));
```

---

## Questions

> 1) Why isn't array-index deletion operating like object-key deletion? (With arrays the reference still seems to exist, but just references undefined. With objects, the reference seems to be deleted entirely.)

It is.

> 2) Is the this.length-- method safe? Could it cause a memory leak, or does altering an object's length attribute also cause a check to run and delete any forgotten indices in the array?

Best not to operate and manage the length yourself.  Historically, different browsers respond differently to *length* manipulation.

The only time I've seen `length` manipulation used in recent years is to clear an array (i.e., `arr.length = 0`).  This is preferred over assigning it to an new empty array (i.e., `arr = []`) for when the array may contain certain properties that should not be lost or re-constructed.

> 3) Do the answers to either of the previous 2 questions vary based on the implementation?

Yes

> 4) What's a good implementation of removeLast?

`arr.pop()` or `arr.splice(-1,1)`

Comment: _which cannot be performed using the `delete` operator._ Prove it!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'm actually editing this answer, give me a minute

Comment: I had forgotten about `pop`, and it looks like you've found the part of MDN I'm looking for! But I'm also curious about the potential for a memory-leak resulting from `[].length` modifications. Is `this.length--` an unsafe operation?

Comment: *"Non-configurable properties cannot be removed. This includes properties of built-in objects like Math, Array(...)"* - but he doesn't want to remove a non-configurable property, neither the Array object nor an index.

Comment: @Kinduser yes you're correct I was in the process of editing as I confused this with another question, which I was answering and copy/pasted the wrong snippet — I think it's updated

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir please instruct how it's wrong.  I wasn't expecting you and *Kind user* to evaluate answers so quickly -- good job to both of you!  I go through a process of post-edit-save-edit-save-edit-save about 3 edit-review cycles and you caught me at initial one :P well done for being so responsive, the community needs more people like you

Comment: "*The only time I've seen length manipulation used in recent years is to clear an array*" - what else would you say would `removeLast` do if not to clear the last index? `.length--` is totally fine.

Comment: @vol7ron thanks for all the edits! This is the answer I was looking for :D

Comment: @Bergi yes it could do that, but I'd be hesitant to do that over some other means; even when clearing the array via length, I've seen it wrapped in try/catch blocks. It could be my own insecurities, but my opinion -- for repetition, it is my opinion -- is to use an already existing or more popular mechanism that is universally tested and used (e.g., `splice`, `pop`); but I shouldn't be the only one to answer this question, as someone with more practice (in QA/support) may be able to better defend `length--` for the breadth of user agents and CLIs available today.