# array.length-=1 vs array.pop()

Tags: javascript, arrays, stack

I know that array is some kind of an object, but it also has numeric indexes. And `arr.length` is a property, which returns not the number of elements in the array, but the last index+1. We can remove the last element using decrement of `length` or function `pop()`. And the question is: What's the difference between these methods?

Comment: you get the item with `pop`...? what is the changing of length for?

Comment: [Is it an antipattern to set an array length in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547315) and [Javascript array length modification implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712345)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some differences:

- `pop` returns the value of the entry that you're removing, assigning to `length` doesn't.
- `pop` is a method call; assigning to `length` is an assignment operation.
- `pop` on an array whose length is `0` returns `undefined` and doesn't change the array. `array.length -= 1` on an array with a `length` of `0` causes an error.

Answer (score 3):

`.pop()` also returns the last element (which is often wanted):

```
const last = array.pop();
// vs
const last = array[array.length - 1];
array.length -= 1;
```

Now you can decide yourself which one of the above is more readable ...